# print lines after finding a key word in perl

Tags: perl, printing, line, keyword

I have a variable $string and i want to print all the lines after I find a keyword in the line (including the line with keyword)

```
$string=~ /apple /;
```

I'm using this regexp to find the key word but I do not how to print lines after this keyword.

Comment: Please, show the bigger picture. Where are the lines coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data in scalar variable we can use several methods

Recommended method

```
($matching) =  $string=~ /([^\n]*apple.+)/s;
print "$matching\n";
```

And there is another way to do it

```
$string=~ /[^\n]*apple.+/s; 
print $&; #it will print the data which is match.
```

If you reading the data from file, try the following

```
while (<$fh>)
{
  if(/apple/)
  {
     print <$fh>;
  }
}
```

Or else try the following one liner

```
perl -ne 'print <> and exit if(/apple/);' file.txt
```

Comment: your first code works but it doesnt print the entire line for the line with the keyword it only prints the rest of the line after the keyword,how can i get around this?

Comment: `/[^\n]*apple.*/s` will match from the start of the line containing 'apple'.
I'm not sure if I like using `print <>` instead of setting a state and printing lines one at a time, it's neat but could be a problem if the file is huge.

Comment: @LHMathies Thanks for your suggestion. But user asking for only after match with containing word. For your second question, Not sure, I hope it won't make a memory problem because it will only print the data like a `cat` command (hope). If I'm storing the data in variable ,  it will make a memory issue otherwise not a problem.

Comment: @maz Post edited. And then start learning the [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @mkHun Notice the first comment by the OP asking how to get the whole first line that contains the word. That was what I was replying to.

Comment: Note that using `..` will fail if it's used in a sub (that's called more than once).

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a flag variable, set it to true when you see the string, print if the flag is true.

```
perl -ne 'print if $seen ||= /apple/'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear where your data is coming from. Let's assume it's a string containing newlines. Let's start by splitting it into an array.

```
my @string = split /\n/, $string;
```

We can then use the flip-flop operator to decide which lines to print. I'm using `\0` as a regex that is very unlikely to match any string (so, effectively, it's always false).

```
for (@string) {
  say if /apple / .. /\0/;
}
```

Comment: For data from a file, you can use `/apple/..0 and print for <>` -- because the constant `0` is compared to the line number and that's never zero. For strings, `/$^/` (note the order) will never match so `/apple/../$^/ and say for @string` is safe.

Comment: @LHMathies, `.. 0==1` is far clearer and more efficient than `.. 0` and `.. /$^/`.

Comment: Note that using `..` will fail if it's used in a sub (that's called more than once).

Comment: @ikegami When using `..`, any constant expression will be converted to an integer and compared to `$.`, so there's no difference between `0==1` and `0`. If you aren't reading lines from a file `$.` could be anything (and initially it's zero) so you need a non-constant expression that is always false.

Comment: @ikegami Good point about using these in a subroutine; `..` will behave in an unexpected manner if it never encounters a true value for the right operand -- it will still be 'on' when the subroutine is next called. In the file case you can get around it with `..eof` which is clearer and does reset the operator state; when iterating over an array you'll have to find some expression that's true for the last element. (Alternatively you can generate a reference to a new unnamed sub each time you want to call it).